# Show that $f'$ is square integrable.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove for twice-differentiable $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that if $f \in L^2([0,\infty))$ and $f'' \in L^2([0,\infty))$, then follows that $f' \in L^2([0,\infty))$.

I know by Cauchy-Schwartz that

$$\left|\int_0^\infty ff'' \right| \leq \int_0^\infty |ff''| \leq \sqrt{\int_0^\infty|f|^2} \sqrt{\int_0^\infty |f''|^2}< \infty$$

I also think I can use integration by parts (is this true for Lebesgue integrals?):

$$\int_0^xff'' = f(x)f'(x) - f(0)f'(0) - \int_0^x|f'|^2$$

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x ff'' = \int_0^\infty ff''$ exists I can claim that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x |f'|^2 < \infty$ if I know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) f'(x)$ exists.

I think that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) f'(x) \neq \pm \infty$ but how can I be sure the limit exists at all?  Can I still use this line of reasoning?

Comment: Double-check the equation you obtained integrating by parts.

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the typo

Comment: In the case of smooth functions this follows easily using Fourier Transforms. It is given that $\hat {f}$ and $x^{2}\hat {f} (x)$ are in $L^{2}$ and you have to show that $x\hat {f} (x)$. This follows from the fact that $|x| \leq \frac {1+x^{2}} {2}$

Comment: I meant $x^{2} \leq \frac {1+x^{4}} 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

To finish, note that $x \mapsto \int_0^x |f'|^2$ is nondecreasing and either $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x |f'|^2$ exists and is finite or the integral diverges to $+\infty$.

We have

$$f(x)f'(x) = f(0)f'(0) + \int_0^x |f'|^2 + \int_0^xff''$$

As shown, the second integral on the RHS converges. Consequently, $f(x)f'(x)$ either approaches a finite limit or tends to $+\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

If the finite limit exists, then we are done.

On the other hand, if $f(x)f'(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ then $\int_0^\infty ff'$ is divergent and

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}|f(x)|^2 =  |f(0)|^2+\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x (f^2)' = |f(0)|^2+\lim_{x \to \infty}2 \int_0^x f f' = +\infty.$$

This implies that $\int_0^\infty |f|^2$ diverges to $+\infty$ -- contradicting the premise $f \in L^2([0,\infty)).$